# ChildThread inside a Parent Thread

Tags: nsthread

Can you please help me in this:

How to create a child thread in a parent thread. And the parent thread should be terminated only after the child thread is terminated. and the parent thread is completed only after completing child thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`NSCondition`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCondition_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCondition). Have the child thread signal the condition on termination. Have the parent wait on the condition. Add a predicate (a bool will do it) to work around the 'spurious signals' issues. See Using Conditions on the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html).

Comment: Note though that your definition of a 'child thread' matches exactly the definition of a function call, so most likely you should use a function call not a 'thread'.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample code of parent thread and child thread program.     Thanks in advance